"Connected but Ghosted: Notify Data Missing in Action with @abandonware/noble!" 
async function cubeNotify(characteristic) {
    console.log(`notifyID:${characteristic.uuid}`);

    await characteristic.subscribe((error) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(`subscribe fail: ${error}`);
        } else {
            console.log('subscribe success');
        }
    });

    characteristic.on('data', (data) => {
        if (data.length === 0) {
            return;
        }
        console.log(data);
    });
}

This code works perfectly fine on Windows! But on macOS... hmm... the 'Subscription success!' message shows up, but no data comes through. What did I miss?
I'm using macOS 15, and I've checked the device—everything seems fine. I tried setting macOS Bluetooth permissions, but it didn't help. I also tried using notify instead of subscribe and on read instead of on data, but no luck. Yet, when I use the LightBlue app, the device's data is received just fine. Is this Noble messing with me?
